# What authentication using SQL Server out of process

Tags: asp.net-membership

That means user name and password will be stored in SQL Server?
What is difference between SQL Server and state server authentication

Answer (score 0):

sqlserver uses an SQL database to store session info. State server uses a windows service called ASP.NET State Service to store session information.

Either one allow for more than one web server to "share" session information across multiple servers.